# What is the difference between PKCS1 v1.5 and PKCS7? Is PKCS7 a superset of specifications in PKCS1 1.5?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, padding, pki, pkcs1

I have a requirement wherein we have to verify the PE binaries generated for an aarch64 platform.

These binaries are then signed using the opensource `sbsign` tool to generate a signed PE binary with PKCS7 `signedData` structure included in the `SECURITY` section of the binary. These binaries have to be verified by the bootloader (in our case `uboot`) before they are loaded.

I stumbled across a patch which made use of the [ARM-software/u-boot](https://github.com/ARM-software/u-boot/blob/master/lib/rsa/rsa-verify.c) to verify the `signedData` section. As can be seen, the functions in this file such as `rsa_verify()` and `rsa_verify_with_keynode()` refer to verifying an RSA PKCS1.5 signature.

My question is, is this the same as verifying the PKCS7 signedData structure? It would be great if someone could help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between PKCS#1 v1.5 and PKCS#7?

PKCS#7 makes use of cryptographic primitives defined by PKCS#1 v1.5.

PKCS#7 is defined in [RFC 2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315). The modern PKCS#1 is [v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf) (also [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017)), and has a modern description of the schemes in PKCS#1 v1.5, including RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.

> Is verifying a PKCS#1 v1.5 signature the same as verifying the PKCS#7 signedData structure?

Verifying a PKCS#7 [`signedData`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#page-11) structure involves verifying a RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 signature, but also a number of important steps before that, including parsing that data structure, and checks which depend on context. `signedData` has features which might not be needed by in a bootloader, like certificates with revocation lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot fgrieu. So to summarize, the signature format(EncryptedDigest within SignedInfo structure in signedData)is governed by PKCS#1 v2.2 (or 1.5 in my case). Since PKCS#7 signedData contains signerInfo structure with EncryptedDigest which is essentially the signature, this EncryptedDigest needs to be verified. Hence, PKCS#7 signedData verification has EncryptedDigest aka signature verification as a critical step which is governed by PKCS#1 v2.2.